# How do you add images to an array?

Tags: java, arrays, polymorphism, image

I am stuck on a project because I have no clue how to store a **picture** into an `array`.

I think it would go in this method

```
public Picture addPicture (Picture pictureAdded) {

  pRef = pictureAdded;
  return pRef;

}
```

Comment: A good start would be to mention what programming language you want to use.

Comment: What is `Picture` class and where is your array ?

Comment: Also, in what kind of array you want to store that Picture object. In a Picture[] array, a byte[] array, or ... ?

Comment: @kocko: No need to nitpick. You can easily assume that they want to store it in a Picture[] array.

Comment: I forgot to put that this is in java but thanks for the feedback everyone, it was useful and helped me

Comment: @Bradley If it was helpful, then you should [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) that answered your question! I'm glad we could help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is [object-oriented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/), which lets you take advantage of [polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) to reuse code and concepts. Since `Picture` extends [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) you can store it in an array like you would any other object.

```
Picture[] pictures = new Picture[10];
pictures[0] = pictureToAdd;
```

If you want to iterate through the array you can do:

```
for(Picture picture : pictures)
{
    // do stuff here
}
```

You can also put `Picture` objects into an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or any other data structure.

```
List<Picture> pictures = new ArrayList<Picture>();
pictures.add(pictureToAdd);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can store it just like you'd store any other object in an array

```
Picture [] parr = new Picture[5];
parr[0] = pictureAdded
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it:

```
Picture[] pictures = new Picture[5]; //This will make an array of 5 pictures
pictures[0] = pictureAdded;
```

You can also use a pre-made class in Java - ArrayList. This way you don't have to worry about array size:

```
ArrayList<Picture> pictures = new ArrayList<Picture>();
pictures.add(new Picture());
Picture pic = pictures.get(0);
```